# using django-oneall as a third-party authentication package for django-rest-framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I was planning on using django-oneall for social-network authentication for my app, but I don't see it listed in the third-party authentication packages suggested for django-rest-framework.  Has anyone used this? If so, is there much extra work involved meaning I might be better off using django-rest-auth along with django-allauth instead?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `django_oneall` uses session authentication it turns out to be pretty simple to setup.

I did need quite a bit of [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653518) figuring it out though.

All you need to do is:

## settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

`django_oneall` handles the session authentication, so that's it.

The only problem I had, which wasn't unique to using `django-oneall` at all was that I didn't realize it expected both the csrftoken cookie **AND** a X-CSRFToken HTTP Header as well.  Unlike most projects where documentation is lacking, the rest framework has lots of excellent documentation - i guess I simply caught with a TL;DR this time.  good to know that the rest framework is easy to integrate with if you're using session authentication.