# django-rest-framework returning 403 response on POST, PUT, DELETE despite AllowAny permissions

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm using a [django-oneall](http://github.com/leandigo/django-oneall) to allow social login session authentication on my site. While it isn't one of the suggested auth providers for django-rest-framework,  `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` uses django's default session authentication. so I thought it should be fairly simple to integrate.

On the permissions side, ultimately I'll use `IsAdmin`, but for development purposes, I just had it set to `IsAuthenticated`. When that returning 403s, I relaxed the permissions to `AllowAny`, but still no dice. Here's my rest framework config:

## settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
     ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}
```

EDIT:

I got this working based on the answer below. It turns out that `rest_framework` expects both the `csrftoken` cookie and a a `X-CSRFToken` Header of the same value, I setup my front-end code to send that header for all ajax requests and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Django REST Framework returns status code `403` under a couple of relevant circumstances:

- When you don't have the required permission level (e.g. making an API request as an unauthenticated user when `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` is `('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',)`.
- When you doing an unsafe request type (POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE - a request that should have side effects), you are using `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` and you've not included your CSRFToken in the requeset.
- When you are doing an unsafe request type and the CSRFToken you've included is no longer valid.

I'm going to make a few demo requests against a test API to give an example of each to help you diagnose which issue you are having and show how to resolve it. I'll be using the `requests` library.

**The test API**

I set up a very simple DRF API with a single model, `Life`, that contains a single field (`answer`, with a default value of `42`). Everything from here on out is pretty straight forward; I set up a `ModelSerializer` - `LifeSerializer`, a `ModelViewSet` - `LifeViewSet`, and a `DefaultRouter` on the `/life` URL route. I've configured DRF to require user's be authenticated to use the API and to use `SessionAuthentication`.

**Hitting the API**

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/life/1/')
# prints (403, '{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}')
print response.status_code, response.content

my_session_id = 'mph3eugf0gh5hyzc8glvrt79r2sd6xu6'
cookies = {}
cookies['sessionid'] = my_session_id
response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/life/1/',
                        cookies=cookies)
# prints (200, '{"id":1,"answer":42}')
print response.status_code, response.content

data = json.dumps({'answer': 24})
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.put('http://localhost:8000/life/1/',
                        data=data, headers=headers,
                        cookies=cookies)
# prints (403, '{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set."}')
print response.status_code, response.content

# Let's grab a valid csrftoken
html_response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/life/1/',
                             headers={'accept': 'text/html'},
                             cookies=cookies)
cookies['csrftoken'] = html_response.cookies['csrftoken']
response = requests.put('http://localhost:8000/life/1/',
                        data=data, headers=headers,
                        cookies=cookies)
# prints (403, '{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}')
print response.status_code, response.content

headers['X-CSRFToken'] = cookies['csrftoken']
response = requests.put('http://localhost:8000/life/1/',
                        data=data, headers=headers,
                        cookies=cookies)
# prints (200, '{"id":1,"answer":24}')
print response.status_code, response.content
```

Comment: hmm... my Ember app is indeed passing the csrf cookie in the request.  I have a reverse proxy setup in apache for my rest api.  Perhaps I need to somehow modify my reverse proxy so it copies the csrf  cookie value into the `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` header?

Comment: i guess I should rather configure ember to always pass the csrftoken cookie value in the header.  that should be easier.

Comment: @ckot I've updated my answer. Forgot that both the header `X-CSRFToken` and the cookie `csrftoken` had to be set.

Comment: thanks. awesome that makes total sense. I'll try it out in a bit, I need to research the configuring ember bit first.  I imagine it's just a `$.ajaxSetup()` or some equivalent

Comment: yep. that worked, **Thank you!** you can't imagine how much time you saved me.  Now I can use `IsAuthenticated` privs.  Once I update my social login/registration page so that it can differentiate between admin and normal users I'll be able to switch to `IsAdmin`!

Answer (score 4):

Just for anyone that might find the same problem.
If you are using viewsets without routers like:

```
user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
user_detail = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})
```

Django Rest framework will return 403 unless you define permission_classes at a class level:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    permission_classes= YourPermisionClass
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake, there is one more circumstance under which DRF returns code 403: if you forget to add `as_view()` to the view declaration in your urls.py file. Just happened to me, and I spent hours until I found where the issue was, so maybe this addition can save some time for someone.

Comment: `as_view` is for django class based views, it has to the best of my knowledge nothing do do with api-urls from django-rest-framework. DRF also does not mention it in their routing documentation (other then for including non-DRF views) http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/ . Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

For those that aren't able to even access their csrftoken from Javascript:

In my case I wasn't able to get the csrftoken from my Javascript code to be able to set it in my ajax POST. It always printed null. I finally discovered that the django CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY environment variable was set to True.

From the Django Documentation

> **CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY**: If this is set to True, client-side JavaScript will not be able to access the CSRF cookie."

Changing CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY to False allowed me to finally get the csrftoken.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY

Comment: Not advisable, as this opens up your app to CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing similar kind of issue after migrating from Django 3 to Django 4 then it might be because of misconfigured `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` in settings file.

One possible cause will be:

In Django 3, the list of `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` contains only domains without protocol.

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['example.com']
```

But in Django 4, the list of `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` should have protocol defined.

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins

Answer (score 0):

One more situation that someone may find is that you get a 403 error on an AllowAny route when you pass an token as null in the "Authorization" header in your request. For example, you may want to allow anyone to use the route but also want to know if the person that used the route is an authenticated user.

E.g.

```
if (token) {
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Token " + token
    }
} else {
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use @csrf_exempt at the top of your POST function
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

example

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def student_api(request):
    request. MethodMethod == 'POST':
       json_data = request. Body
       stream = io.BytesIO(json_data)
       pythondata = JSONParser().parse(stream)
       serializer = StudentSerializer(data=pythondata)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           res = {'msg': 'Data Created'}
           json_data = JSONRenderer().render(res)
           return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
       json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.errors)
       return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```